# What is the purpose of getTemplate() in knockout Js Magento 2?

Tags: magento, data-binding, knockout.js, magento2

I'm learning Knockout JS in Magento 2. There is a function getTemplate() which syntax looks like this  . I want to know its working and purpose.

FilePath: app/code/CloudyDigitals/LearnKnockout/view/frontend/templates/knockout.phtml

```
<div id="ko-test" data-bind="scope:'ko-example'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#ko-test": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "ko-example": {
                            "component": "CloudyDigitals_LearnKnockout/js/knockout"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Magento user, but assuming this is standard knockoutjs, getTemplate I think will be returning either a template name as a string, or a template shaped object.

> If you just supply a string value, KO will interpret this as the ID of a template to render. The data it supplies to the template will be your current model object.

[Knockout JS Template Binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)